# Stopwatch counter speed double when start is triggered second time

Tags: javascript, web-frontend

so I know that people here had same Issue, and i have it to and just Don't know how to apply fix on my code.
So basicly, when u Click start 2nd  time in a row, speed double.

Here is my code

```
    let secondsNumber = 0
let minutesNumber = 0
let hoursNumber = 0

function start() {
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        secondsNumber++
        seconds.innerHTML = secondsNumber
        if (secondsNumber == 60) {
            secondsNumber = 0
            minutes.innerHTML = ++minutesNumber + '0'
        }
        if (minutesNumber == 60) {
            minutesNumber = 0
            hours.innerHTML = ++hoursNumber
        }
    }, 1000)



}


function stop() {
    clearInterval(interval)
}


function reset() {
    clearInterval(interval)
    secondsNumber = 00
    minutesNumber = 00
    hoursNumber = 00
    seconds.innerHTML = secondsNumber + '0'
    minutes.innerHTML = minutesNumber + '0'
    hours.innerHTML = hoursNumber + '0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can limit the button click like this

- Use `interval` value to limit `start()` function

```js
let interval;

function start() {
    if (interval) {
      return;
    }

    interval = setInterval(() => {
        secondsNumber++;
        seconds.innerHTML = secondsNumber;
        if (secondsNumber == 60) {
            secondsNumber = 0;
            minutes.innerHTML = ++minutesNumber + '0';
        }
        if (minutesNumber == 60) {
            minutesNumber = 0;
            hours.innerHTML = ++hoursNumber;
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

- Disable your start button when `interval` has value
- Set `interval` to undefined when `stop()` and `reset()` functions are executed

```js
function stop() {
  if (interval){
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = undefined;
  }
}

function reset() {
    if (interval) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      interval = undefined;
      secondsNumber = 00;
      minutesNumber = 00;
      hoursNumber = 00;
      seconds.innerHTML = secondsNumber + '0';
      minutes.innerHTML = minutesNumber + '0';
      hours.innerHTML = hoursNumber + '0';
    }
}
```

---

Now there will be no second click on start function.

Comment: This helped, and solved one issue, but 2 more appeared. when I click pause, and then click start button again, it dosent unpause the timer, and also when i reset time, i am unable to start it again, unless i refresh the page

Comment: Can you add the HTML to your question? @EmanuelRajicMiskovic

Answer (score 1):

You can just temporarily disable the button until reset/stop button is clicked

```
function start() {
    // I am assuming your start button has id "start"
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = true;
    let interval = setInterval(() => {
        secondsNumber++
        seconds.innerHTML = secondsNumber
        if (secondsNumber == 60) {
            secondsNumber = 0
            minutes.innerHTML = ++minutesNumber + '0'
        }
        if (minutesNumber == 60) {
            minutesNumber = 0
            hours.innerHTML = ++hoursNumber
        }
        
    }, 1000)

}


function stop() {
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = false;
    clearInterval(interval)
}


function reset() {
    document.getElementById("start").disabled = false;
    
    clearInterval(interval)
    secondsNumber = 00
    minutesNumber = 00
    hoursNumber = 00
    seconds.innerHTML = secondsNumber + '0'
    minutes.innerHTML = minutesNumber + '0'
    hours.innerHTML = hoursNumber + '0'
}
```